# Get user Apple Music playlists from an iOS application

Tags: ios, apple-music

From my iOS app, I need to get all the user playlist available in the Apple Music application.

Is it possible without the MusicKit SDK (prior iOS11) ?

Answer (score 0):

Support back to iOS 3.0 with MPMediaPlaylist.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaplaylist

Comment: can we get playlist from iTunes Store ? Prior to iOS 11

Comment: iTunes Store only has albums. Using the iTunes Search API you can get all albums for any country. https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/